# Difficulty to eat healthy food and weight loss

Tags: weight-loss, diet, training, protein, food

First of all a couple of background lines to my question, so you can better understand what I am talking about. 
I am a 31 y.o. man, working pretty much all day at my desk, with little-to-no-time at all for sports, after I've dealt with tons of other daily things.
In the last 2 years I've put on a lot of weight (92kg weight x 1.76m height) because my habits changed a lot (I used to walk to go to my job - because I had time to do it - , I went dancing every Saturday - I had friends where I lived, now where I do I don't even have discos in a 30km radius - and so on...).
I go in fitness-studio twice a week (rarely once, I always try to keep these hours as "untouchable" given the amount of other things to do), where I do in the following order: 10 minutes of cardio, 2 times a "circle" (each exercise works on a different muscle) without pause between the exercises but with a pause between the circles and at the end 20 minutes of cardio again.
I have a nasty problem with food. I can avoid eating junk food, but I cannot eat all the healthy stuff there is, since most vegetables make me **really** puke. Same goes with fruit and most of the cheese. I do eat a lot of carbohydrates (there is not much left in the world with all I excluded, is there?).

I may sound "polarized" wanting some answers rather than others, but I am aware of what I can and can't do and answers like "go out and run" or "eat vegetables" will just disappoint me.

I cannot find more time to do exercise. Some days I am really exhausted and I **need** to rest.
I cannot *try* to eat what I don't, because it makes me fell sick (literally) and I don't have time or money to sit by a psychologist and work that out.
Is there *anything at all* that could help me? I am willing to try: diets (please consider my problems with food), different training (shouldn't exceed the time I have), integrators (vitamins, fat burners, carbohydrates absorbers, proteins, ...).

Comment: Can you eat boiled eggs?

Answer (score 5):

A huge reality you need to embrace is that if you do not make sizable time and adjustments for your health now, you will make time and adjustments for long term and generally incurable health problems in the future.

You might be "busy" now with life commitments, but being on a kidney dialysis machine will make you even "busier". This isn't about having a clean or dirty car, where you still have a car that works it's just whether or not it looks good. This is about whether or not you are healthy or ill, and live long or die early. It's really just that simple. And if you don't prioritize your health now, you'll be forced to later with chronic illness.

I whole heartily disagree with the notion that "a calorie is a calorie". A lot of that stems from the [Twinkie diet](http://www.cnn.com/2010/HEALTH/11/08/twinkie.diet.professor/), but it's taken out of context. The metabolic impact of 100 calories of refined carbohydrates is much different than the metabolic impact of 100 calories of protein. Refined carbohydrates (what you eat for lunch every day, as noted in one of your comments) spikes your blood sugar, releases insulin, and promotes fat storage. The Twinkie diet study lasted 10 weeks, and people have wrongly extrapolated it's relevance.

[If you keep doing it, you will become insulin resistant](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19351/zyzz-body-without-steroids/19353#19353) which means fatty acids will float around in your blood vessels, sticking to the walls, and your circulatory system will increase blood pressure to compensate for the reduced diameters.

My prescription, for whatever it's worth:

1. Watch [Fed Up](http://fedupmovie.com/) ([this link](http://vidbull.com/zcslf5o665al.html) currently works to stream for free). It does a very good job of explaining food, calories, and metabolic disorders. Buy a copy and give it to a friend as well, it's very much worth it.
2. Prioritize your fitness. Quit your job, get another one that you can walk to. Do whatever it takes to put your fitness first because **you will** pay the price if you don't. And it won't be at a time and place of your choosing. If someone put a gun to your head and told you to go to the gym or run every day for 45 minutes, you'd figure it out.

For most people your early 30's is really the age when you pick which road you want to go down. Your youth is going away, and you either need to work against the steady decline of health or just make excuses and let it slide.

Apologies is this isn't overly cheery, but it's the truth the best as I know it.

Comment: Hi Eric and thanks for your reply first of all. Look, I am not hyper-obese. I weight more or less 10 kg more than I am supposed to not to be considered over-weight anymore, so in the long term I really don't believe that I will be stuck to a dialisys machine.
Sorry but I am not even considering quitting my job, since I am lucky to work for a healthy company, do a job I like and that I studied for and that at the end of the month provides me with (good) money. I get what you're saying though and I do prioritize my fitness during these "holy" hours per week.

Comment: It happens though that I am just NOT ABLE to go 2 times a week (rarely as I explained - but these week is one of those - ). What I CAN do in relation to your answer is to avoid eating pasta at lunch. Would you then care to elaborate on that? What could I eat that a) I can cook and freeze so that I can b) heat in microwave and heat at office ?

Comment: 92Kg is closer to 20Kg over a good fit weight ... since you're not likely to pack much muscle under your confessed exercise regimen. You are looking for a silver bullet as a mean to not change your habits. You will be disappointed by all the answers you get.

Answer (score 3):

To lose weight, you do not need to eat "healthy" or eat vegetables. Weight gain and loss comes down to the energy balance equation, or net calories (weight changes) = calories in - calories out. The reason exercise helps to lose weight is because it increases the calories out number, but it is not strictly necessary with good diet (though it will increase the ratio of fat loss to muscle loss).

Try using a calorie counting app or food diary, and keeping your daily intake at or below 2,000 calories. It doesn't matter if it comes from meat, dairy, carbs, vegetables, starch, etc, so long as your intake stays below your output (at a 500 calorie/day deficit, about 1lb a week will be lost).

If you're lacking on vegetable content I would definitely recommend that you take a daily multivitamin at least, for health purposes.

**Note** - I do advise finding a way to fix the vegetable problem however, and what I suggest is probably not the best long-term plan for overall health. It is just what will help lose weight.

Comment: This is a good answer. I'd like to add that exercise is likely to increase appetite, so 500 burned calories is not 500 "won" calories, since you'll be hungrier as well. Either way, eat less than you use during the day and you'll lose weight. Also, most studies where people try to start doing exercise result in no or almost no weight loss.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you won't be entirely happy with the answers we give you. You will definitely have to work on your ability to eat veggies and fruit. Supplements are ok and you should take them if you really, really, really can't eat any foods like veggies or fruit. However, since you don't have time for a gym, the only possible solution would be if you just lower your daily calorie intake. Try to eat less pasta and eat more whole grains instead.