# Android app for fat people

Tags: fat, app

I'm fat.

I want to do exercises & look like Zyzz but I get bored fast. It would help me if I could set a goal. Let's say 30 minutes per day. So I'm looking for an app where I can set a daily countdown. I would start when I do exercises and stop if when i stop doing exercises. If it doesn't reach 0, what's left should be added to the countdown next day. Is there such an app?

Comment: related: [Fitness app advice](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25476/fitness-app-advice)

Answer (score 1):

You need [a solid training program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091) + [solid nutrition](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-for-better-fat-loss/) + [discipline](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25438/difficulty-to-eat-healthy-food-and-weight-loss/25492#25492) to stick with it.

Regarding an app, some people like [jefit](https://www.jefit.com/).

[Zyzz](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19351/zyzz-body-without-steroids/) died at the age of 22 in a Thai bath house of a heart attack, no help coming from his use of anabolic steroids and anphetamine like substances (fat burners): try not to be like him too much.

If you want to destroy your body and die, by all means focus on sub 5% body fat in the next 6 months. If you want to look good, feel good, and have a healthy body for as long as possible, have realistic goals and use tried and [true training programs](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091).

Comment: Tell me more about this "destroy your body and die" program -- sounds hardcore.

Comment: @Noumenon - Read what he is saying. It's not a program.

Comment: @JohnP Joke failed to execute, that's all. I should've said 'sounds like the best thing since CrossFit'.