# Should I start taking supplements other than my protein?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, supplements, hiit

I started my journey towards a healthier lifestyle on January 2014 weighing 253 lbs, I did weight routines and HIIT(once a week) followed a STRICT diet and managed to drop to 218lbs by the end of the year. I faced some slight depression the first half of this 2015 which caused me to stopped working out for that period of time, and I've been intensively working out since June 06 and watching my diet. I feel myself getting stronger although I wish I could lose fat at the same rate I earn strength. I have been told I should use supplements to burn fat, but I'm scared since I don't really know what I would be getting into. Any suggestions?

PS: I do want to lose weight but still look somewhat built, I was a size 40 and now I'm 36 but I still have that extra fatty areas and visceral fat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are supplements you can take that will allow you to lose fat faster than without. Just looking at the [ECA stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECA_stack) for a minute, from a [peer reviewed study](http://www.nature.com/ijo/journal/v26/n5/full/0802023a.html):

> Conclusions: In this 6-month placebo-controlled trial, herbal
>   ephedra/caffeine (90/192 mg/day) promoted body weight and body fat
>   reduction and improved blood lipids without significant adverse
>   events.

However, [numerous deaths can be attributed to ephedra and ephedra like substances](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11117974):

> The use of dietary supplements that contain ephedra alkaloids may pose
>   a health risk to some persons. These findings indicate the need for a
>   better understanding of individual susceptibility to the adverse
>   effects of such dietary supplements.

No one is going to credibly argue that something like the widely consumed ECA stack is ineffective. Also, no one with much brain power is going to going around recommending it.

As you noted, it was the strict adherence to your diet that made the biggest difference and at a high (>20%, for males) body fat, diet is the largest valve to play with by far. I'm not going to recommend an ECA stack for anyone, but the generally successful results I've seen are from folks who use it on a short term basis to dip into the <10% range, [because the lower your body fat goes the easier it is to add body fat](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19353/7091).

My honest advice would be to use an effective strength training program that has you lifting every other day, and then go for runs or long (1 hour+) walks on the other days. That schedule, combined with a strict diet, will scrub fat quite consistently. [And remember that strength training has a higher impact to fat loss than cardio](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-for-better-fat-loss/19117#19117).

"Fat burners" you can largely ignore for your entire fitness life and have great results. If you do venture down that road, I would ***strongly*** encourage you to:

- Skip HIIT
- Don't run in the heat
- Stay very hydrated
- Start with a much lower dose than whatever the [bro-science](http://www.bodybuilding.com/) on the Internet tells you
- Tell your doctor what you're doing.

Fat burners will increase your blood pressure, induce [tachycardia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachycardia), and raise your core temperature: deadly things if your body has existing cardiac issues or is trying to cool you down during normal exercise. People do die.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should stick to what I'm currently doing just include more low intensity cardio?

Comment: Basically. I don't know your strength training program, but for sure make sure it's effective  (strong lifts, starting strength). And lower intensity cardio so that it doesn't interfere with your strength program.

Comment: Current is a 3 day program with decent weight to complete 4 sets per circuit(each muscle has 4 circuits): day 1: chest, triceps, shoulders day 2: leg day day 3: back, biceps, forearms

Comment: I would scrap that and check out the two I mentioned, you'll have great results.

Comment: do you have any blog i could follow?